# How can I change tagline in title tag "Just another wordpress site"?

Tags: title

I need change the tagline to a custom, specific tagline, further describing my business such as - "self-funded revenue increase" but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the *tag line* in your admin panel under

`Settings > General > Tagline`

There you can change it to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

On the dashboard under appearance click on customise. Then click on site identity. The tagline is the option you need to change.